# Displaying collection of double object in non-default way

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to display collection of double objects.

Following code works fine:

```
namespace WpfApplication4
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<double> collection1 { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        collection1=new ObservableCollection<double>();

        for (double d = 0.0; d < 1.0; d += 0.1)
        {
            nm.wartosci.Add(d);
        }

        DataContext=this;

    }
}
```

XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding wartosci}" >
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

But what if I want to display objects in different way. When I add DataTemplate to ListView, so it looks as below:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding wartosci}" >
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Visual studio returns an exception:

XamlParseException was unhandled
Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.

I suppose I should write something into `{Binding}`, but what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Works fine, but whith this solution data-binding doesn't work - when I change values in displayed TextBoxes, it doesn't affect values in collection, when I check them while debuging.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
I had a little more thought about this and it actually cannot work that way.
What your are trying to do is actually the same thing as trying to assign a new value to a parameter. That is why TwoWay binding cannot work.

One way to do it would be to have a wrapper around your double. Therefore the wrapper object is not changed but you can access and change the double value inside the wrapper.

WrapperClass:

```
public class WrapClass
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

...

public ObservableCollection<WrapClass> Collection1 { get; set; }
```

Your XAML:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value }"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Works fine, but whith this solution data-binding doesn't work - when I change values in displayed TextBoxes, it doesn't affect values in collection, when I check them while debuging.

Comment: Yes, that is what OneWay means. It only updates from your property to the GUI but not the other way around. If you want TwoWay binding, this is not the solution. Solution given by @Somedust should work I think.

Comment: Unfortunetly it doesn't, the result is the same as with your solution.